# Is this Big-O Notation Correct for Simple List Input Function?

Tags: python, function, big-o

Suppose we have the following function:

```
def multi(list):
    """Take a list of numbers and modify it in place by
    multiplying every 3rd number by 2."""
    for index in range(2, len(list), 3):
        list[index] *= 2
    return list
```

Would the big-O notation of this be `O(n)` given that the time required to run the function depends on the length of the list used as an input, which increases linearly?

Comment: Just a side note: Have in mind that big-O notation generally applies to algorithms rather than implementations and it is a concern when the input grows arbitrarily. When writing your own code, you should indeed start by worrying about computational complexity, but afterwards there are many more concerns that result in considerable variations in speedup.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The loop runs `len(list) / 3` times (plus/minus a constant and some rounding, but lower orders are irrelevant anyway), and the `/ 3` is irrelevant due to being a constant factor, so the loop is O(n).

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. Specifically we would have `O((n-2) / 3))`, but then we drop all constant terms and end up with a final answer of O(n).